# Authenticating users using Windows logon

Tags: c#, .net, security, authentication

I want to try and avoid forcing users to logon to use my applications, so I am wondering if there is a secure was I can use a Windows authenticated user?

I can't see this working, personally, because at some point my application is going to have to send the users login username and grab the permissions.

Assuming this connection is encrypted...I'm guessing a malicious user could still decompile my application, change the code to impersonate a user and recompile. Even if I obfuscated the code, I am sure there must exist methods around this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please provide more details? Look like: your application have connection to Active Directory? The database already configuration for it? You should reference to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa570351.aspx to know how to connect Active Directory and take verify username and password.

Comment: Why will the application have to send the username somewhere? Aren't we talking about a local application that is running under a user's account and doing local stuff? Or are we talking about a web application?

Comment: We are talking about a local .NET application doing stuff locally under a users and sending it to the server. User permissions need to be managed remotely.

Comment: Is the user account running the local .NET application known at the server (domain environment)? In this case mechanisms exist so the server can see who is connecting and use the user account Information for permissions. Otherwise you'll need to authenticate with a user account known at the server first.